# "KeyError" while rename files per multiple conditions/dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Having a hard time to append directory to filenames based on multiple conditions.

The aim is to prefix the 1st parent directory's name to filenames of those files only that meet all 3 conditions:

- files are located **inside a subdirectory** of a directory ending with `=camID` (e.g., ...`=d5`) AND
- `['append_dir_to_filename'] =` is **set** to `1` AND
- they are `raw_file` (by extension).

Result would look like: `DSCN101_ND52000.nef`

**Before** and **after**:

```
CWD                                      
    01_camdir=d5                    #dirname ends with "camID" 'd5', 'g7', 'a9'
          /aaa/ .nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav
    02_camdir=g7                     
          /bbb/ddd/ .cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdir=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ .mp4,.jpg,.avi,.thm
    04_camdir                     
          / .mp4,.jpg,.avi

CWD                                      
    01_camdir=d5                       
          /aaa/aaa_.nef, aaa_.jpg, aaa_.avi, .wav            #appended raw files
    02_camdir=g7                      
          /bbb/ddd/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4                            #NOT appended, 'append_dir_to_filename'] = 0 
    03_camdir=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ xxx_.mp4, xxx_.jpg, xxx_.avi, .thm   #appended raw files
    04_camdir                     
          /.mp4,.jpg,.avi                                    #do not appended, dir not in lookup
```

**Code**:

Gives `in <listcomp>` and `KeyError: 'append_dir_to_filename'` error for the 1st line:

```
camDirs = [os.path.join(cwd, x) for x in next(os.walk(cwd))[1] if x[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']]
for camDir in camDirs:
        camID = camDir[-2:]
        for rootDir, _, files in os.walk(camDir):
            prefix = os.path.basename(rootDir)
            for file in files:
                if (any(x for x in config[camID] if file.endswith(x)) and prefix[-2:] not in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
                    os.rename(os.path.join(rootDir, file), os.path.join(rootDir, "{}_{}".format(prefix, file)))
```

**Table**:

```
#'g7', 'd5' are called "camID"
config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
    'so': {},
}
config['g7']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 0          #set to 1, append dir name
config['g7']['raw_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')    #files to append

config['d5']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1          #set to 1, append dir name
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')    #files to append

config['a9']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1          #set to 0, do not append dir name
config['a9']['raw_file'] = ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')    #files to append
```

In other words, append  directory name for **select** photo and video filetypes (but not for other filetypes) from **select** cameras (but not from all cameras). The info in respect of which files and which cameras to append is in the table.

**For example** (sorting media files from memory cards of different camera types):  If  a directory is ending with ...`=d5` (or whatever else is in the lookup table), then, per the lookup table, all `raw_file` (`nef, jpg, avi`) filenames **within** the ...`=d5` directory are to be appended with 1 level parent directory name like `dirname_origfilename.nef`. If `['append_dir_to_filename'] = 0`, then do NOT append the directory name. One exception: if the files located immediately in the directory ending with ...`=d5` (or `=g7`, or `=so`..), then do not append.

Comment: The whole question seems a little bit twisted (at least to me). So, what is the technical problem here? Could you describe the current status and the desired one (the tree structure at the beginning isn't helping a lot), and thus eliminate the possibility of an _XY_ problem? Second, are you talking about file/folder name processing or filesystem operations?

Comment: I made some clarifications in OP.  Problem is to properly call the values from the table to the code. so it converts the before tree to an after tree (appends dir names `aaa` and `xxx` to filenames per the table rules). That's it.

Comment: I think I understood (at least a part of) it. One comment though, I would structure my code so that I am able to run it more than once(for testing purposes) without too much trouble (`os.rename` from your snippet rules out this). So, you might want to break the problem in 2: figure out a structure that would best match your desired file structure, and **only** then start moving from the existing state.

Comment: I do appreciate your comments, the problem is I am a new to python, but will experiment along the lines you suggest. Thank you.